# Why doesn't any short circuit in this property?

Tags: python, any

`self.ts_end` is None. I would any expect `any` to yield `True` after the first evaluation.

```
    @property
    def is_active(self):
       return any((self.ts_end is None, self.ts_end > datetime.now(timezone.utc)))
```

It crashes on the second comparison. however.

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

It's `any`'s iteration of its argument that can be short-circuited. In this case, the tuple still has to be *constructed* before `any` starts iterating over it. It's the same as if you had written

```
@property
def is_active(self):
   t = (self.ts_end is None, self.ts_end > datetime.now(timezone.utc))
   return any(t)
```

There's little reason to use `any` here; just use `or`:

```
@property
def is_active(self):
   return (self.ts_end is None
            or self.ts_end > datetime.now(timezone.utc))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an inappropriate use of `any`. It does short circuit, but it isn't even getting called here, because you were first building a tuple with the result of both tests. The intended behaviour can be written `self.ts_end is None or self.ts_end > datetime.now(timezone.utc)`, since [`or` evaluates its left subexpression first](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). You could also build an iterable that evaluates as needed instead of a tuple, e.g.:

```
def checker():
    yield self.ts_end is None
    yield self.ts_end > datetime.now(timezone.utc)
return any(checker())
```

The expected behaviour occurs in lazy languages like Haskell, where structures can evaluate on demand. Python uses more explicit evaluation order, more like C.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a tuple inside your `any`, so the tuple gets evaluated first, there's no short-circuiting since the value passed (the tuple) is not a generator or iterable. The tuple contents get evaluated before getting to the use of `any`. You can understant the execution happening in this order:

1. `self.ts_end is None`
2. `self.ts_end > datetime.now(timezone.utc)`
3. `any(...)`
4. `return`